# Using pd.Series.value_counts in Python. Using numpy.where, numpy.unique to replace array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have this code:-

```
y = digits.target

print(y[31:60])

with output [9 5 5 6 5 0 9 8 9 8 4 1 7 7 3 5 1 0 0 2 2 7 8 2 0 1 2 6 3]

y = digits.target

ans_2 = pd.Series.value_counts(y)

ans = ans_2.sort_index()

with output 
0    178
1    182
2    177
3    183
4    181
5    182
6    181
7    179
8    174
9    180
```

Now, I want to write a code to create a new `array` in which  +1 replaces 9  in every occurrence and  All other entries (i.e., the digits  0 through  8 ) should be replaced by  −1. Also, create a Pandas Series (with a sorted index) that records the counts of each class Pandas Series with the integers  −1−  and  +1 on the index (sorted in increasing order) and the corresponding counts as the data. I want to use these functions to solve it using `numpy.where`, `numpy.unique` and `pandas.Series.value_counts`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` first:

```
y = digits.target


new = np.where(y == 9, 1, -1)

s = pd.Series.value_counts(new).sort_index()
print (s)
-1    26
 1     3
dtype: int64
```

Or you can count in `np.unique`:

```
a, b = np.unique(new, return_counts=True)

s = pd.Series(b, index=a)
print (s)
-1    26
 1     3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have an additional question following the same. How to add Pandas DataFrame with the categories  −1−1  and  +1+1  in ascending order as the index and with two columns: train and test.
The entries of each row, then, are the number of occurrences of each category in the training target y_digits_train and the testing target y_digits_test respectively.

Comment: @n53 - Not sure if understand, can you create expected output from data from question by edit?